# facebook graph sdk 2.5 only returning id and name

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've seen other stack questions but their solutions dont appear to be helping me at all.

I am trying to get profile information when I have an external access token that has been returned from an oauth login using

```
Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook
```

I have the returned access token and now want to request get some of the user profile data.

In post man I have tried the following GET

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/{user-id}?fields=about,name,email&access_token={token}
```

where I got the user-id by calling

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/me?access_token={token}
```

(which i think is an unnecessary step).

I have also tried the following

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/me?fields=about,name,email&access_token={token}
```

In every instance I only get the id and name fields returned. However, I have noticed if I do the following;

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/me?fields=email&access_token={token}
```

only the id is returned (i assume as I have not specifically asked for the name).

Any ideas why I am not being returned the data please?

**UPDATED**

If I call the following end point;

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/{user-id}/permissions?access_token={token}
```

I get the following data returned;

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "permission": "public_profile",
            "status": "granted"
        }
    ]
}
```

So I assume that I need to request the permissions of the app?

Comment: The user need to grant the email permission to you

Comment: Thought so how do I request this access after the oath login. Is it in the app setting on the Facebook site?

Comment: You ask for the permission when the user logs in

Comment: Ok currently it's just closing done though. I don't get the 'my app is requesting access to the following information' which I get after the redirect login from Google for instance. Where about do I send the request please?

Comment: Ok for instance when I go to the app settings page -> app review, the approved items are email, public_profile and user_friends so I would have thought I would get the request when I redirect for the login?

Comment: You need to ask the user for the permission. That the permission is approved just means that you are allowed to use it.

Comment: Which is currently what I am doing (to get the token anyway I cut this part out of the question). The user clicks the login button which then redirects to Facebook for the login. The user then logs in and I am given the token. Now when I do this with google it then gives as second screen saying 'my app requests the following info' to which I click allow. It doesn't however trigger this with the fb login. So I suppose at what point and how do I send the request for there file info. Is this when I initially send out the oauth request?

Comment: Read the documentation for Facebook login. It tells you where to specify permissions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, The ASP.NET permissions request isn't very clear on the facebook developers page. The issue is that the request for information is set in the

```
FacebookAuthenticationOptions
```

set during the startup of the application. The additional permissions are request at this point by add to the scope;

```
var options = new FacebookAuthenticationOptions
{
    AppId = "Your App ID",
    AppSecret = "Your App Secret",
};
options.Scope.Add("user_friends");
options.Scope.Add("email");
```

Also, to note during the request the fields are not sent by default and must be requested.

Links to the available permissions can be found here;

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions